# Python code written on Ubuntu, with inconsistent tab space

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, indentation

i'm a beginner, and i have just started using python on ubuntu. the code given below has been edited twice to weed out the indentation errors, but the same error persists.

```
 try: 
        f = int(data['value']) 
        print (f)
        if f > max or f < min:
            response =print("done!") 
    except Exception as e: 
        print ("Error",e)
```

it says that the error is in the if statement and the error is "inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"

Comment: Do some research on Python coding guidelines. In particular PEP 8 and PEP 225 (if I remember correctly) are relevant. They say that you should not use tabs in Python sourcecode but indent with four spaces. That's probably what you're doing wrong. Also, it helps using an editor or IDE that displays spaces and tabs, so you can distinguish the two.

Comment: If my answer was an answer to your question, please mark it as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

Well, the `except`should be at the same "height" or level as the `try`. You also had an extra indentation on the try sector! Remember, python works with indentation only, no `{}`are used!

```
try: 
    f = int(data['value']) 
    print (f)
    if f > max or f < min:
        response =print("done!") 
except Exception as e: 
    print ("Error",e)
```

Comment: It did not work because...? Same `inconsistent use of tabs `? @Sonu

Comment: sorry for the late reply!

Comment: I removed the tabs too but the same error showed up, that is I rewrote the whole code and the same error persisted...

Comment: Python works with tab. So every `{` that opens is a `tab`and every `}` that closes is an `untab`. @Sonu